# Different machines testing for same thing

Tags: water

For a chemistry report, we were given a sample of water and a variety of machines to test it with - giving their respective results about whatever aspect they were testing (eg pH, metal ion concentration etc). However the issue is that two of the machines tested for the same thing (concentration of metals in the water). What should I do in this case, now that I have 2 sets of data about the same thing? Should I discard one? Should I keep both and use it for comparison (although the results do differ somewhat between them)? I feel that doing something like averaging would be very invalid, and it has me very conflicted.

If it helps, the machines in question are AAS and ICP.

Comment: If possible repeat your analysis to make sure that an error has not crept in that you were unaware of. This would invalidate averaging. Also read up about the two techniques, one may be inherently more accurate/sensitive than the other or one may be subject to interference  from some types of metal ions or other species.

Comment: There are often standard solutions you can run to ensure the instrument's giving you the values you'd expect. NIST has a lot of standard solutions, as do commercial providers. Porphyrin's suggestion is a good one from a theoretical perspective, and if you have experimental data you should be able to decide how best to handle your data.